# assigning direct input to weight of a neural network in python

Tags: python, numpy, keras, neural-network, xor

[Neural network based XOR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJA4M.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import keras
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,),use_bias=False)) # hidden layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='softmax',use_bias=False)) # output layer
w1=np.zeros((2,2)) # two input neurons for two neurons at the hidden layer
w2=np.zeros((2,1)) # two input neurons for one output neuron
def __init__(self,x1,x2):
        self.x1=x1
        self.x2=x2
        w1[0,0]=not x2
        w1[0,1]=0
        w1[1,0]=0
        w1[1,1]=not x1
w2[0,0]=1
w2[1,0]=1
model.set_weights([w1, w2])
x = np.array([
[0, 0],
[0, 1],
[1, 0],
[1, 1],
])
model.predict(x)
```

I want to implement 2 input XOR gate for the above shown neural network. I want to assign weights directly as not x1, not x2 to get outputs. I tried with different Activation functions. When linear, sigmoid, softmax activation functions are used at output, all outputs obtained are  0's, 0.5's, 1's respectively. Kindly help me in getting correct output.
I am using python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

So, with such such a small network, you cannot get the output of XOR function. You need to add more dense layer in middle.

This is not hidden layer, this is the input layer (you have also given input shape in it):

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,),use_bias=False))
```

Since weights are zero, inputs to last layer (output layer) is zero too. Then using the activations, you're getting correct outputs. Check the functions and give input as 0, you'll get your output.

`Linear - f(0)=0` - [Linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function)

`Sigmoid - f(0)=0.5` - [Sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)

`Softmax - f(0)=1` - [Softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)

If you want to give not x1, not x2 as inputs, you could do:

```
X = 1-X
```

Comment: I have taken above XOR as an example. If the DNN has 7 layers where in the 6th layer weight has to be assigned as x5, then can I directly assign `w[0,0]=x5`

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810702/modify-layer-parameters-in-keras) check this if it helps

Comment: [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47895/getting-the-weights-of-intermediate-layer-in-keras) check this too